# full text search using pdo '?' instead of :some_term

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to perform a full text search on a column in a table in which i've added the fulltext index to, but i want to use the pdo construct '?' instead of :some_term. It's not working. Here is my code snippet. Any ideas?:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table (MATCH ($column0) AGAINST ?) OR (MATCH ($column1) AGAINST ?) OR (MATCH ($column5) AGAINST ?) OR (MATCH ($column6) AGAINST ?) ORDER BY id DESC");

            if($stmt->execute(array("$query", "$query", "$query", "$query"))){

while($data_fetch = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {some code...}
}
```

When I try to search using this code, it simply does nothing. I don't want to use bindParam, I want to use execute(array...)

Comment: Does the same query work with named parameters instead?

Comment: No. It produces the same result.

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting both in your db connection as well as n php?